# How to add more than 2 filters in search_filter of Salesforce Marketing Cloud Fuel SDK - Python

Tags: python, pyspark, soap, data-science, salesforce-marketing-cloud

How can I append more than 2 filters in the ***search_filter*** of **FuelSDK - Python** which I am using to access Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Lets say there are 3 filters:

```
name_filter = {'Property' : 'Name','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : name}
age_filter = {'Property' : 'Age','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : age}
country_filter = {'Property' : 'Country','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : country}
```

***Now here in the search_filter how to include all the above three filters since there are only two options i.e LeftOperand and RightOperand? If using FuelSdk it's not possible then what is the other way I could do the same?***

```
row = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Row()
row.auth_stub = stubObj
row.CustomerKey = customerKey
row.search_filter = {'LeftOperand': name_filter, 'LogicalOperator':'AND', 'RightOperand':age_filter}
```

**PS:**
**I also tried nesting these filters but that also didn't worked.** *For Example:*

```
name_filter = {'Property' : 'Name','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : name}
age_filter = {'Property' : 'Age','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : age}
country_filter = {'Property' : 'Country','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : country} 

complex_filter1={'LeftOperand': name_filter, 'LogicalOperator':'AND', 'RightOperand':age_filter}

complex_filter2={'LeftOperand': complex_filter1, 'LogicalOperator':'AND', 'RightOperand':country_filter}
```

Comment: Hi..were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Hey @Prim, didn't find it yet.